# How to get each vector / column name inside a map function in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, purrr

I am new in R and applying a `plotting function` to see `counts` of `all factors` of `each factor column`.

**df**

```
install.packages("gapminder")
library(gapminder)

gapminder %>% head()

########### output ###############

country continent   year    lifeExp pop gdpPercap
<fct>   <fct>   <int>   <dbl>   <int>   <dbl>
Afghanistan Asia    1952    28.801  8425333 779.4453
Afghanistan Asia    1957    30.332  9240934 820.8530
Afghanistan Asia    1962    31.997  10267083    853.1007
Afghanistan Asia    1967    34.020  11537966    836.1971
Afghanistan Asia    1972    36.088  13079460    739.9811
Afghanistan Asia    1977    38.438  14880372    786.1134
```

**Issue**: I am not able to get the column name as chart title in below code:

```
gapminder %>% 
  select_if(is.factor) %>% 

  map(function(feature) {
    count(data.frame(x = feature), x) %>% 

  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = n)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +

  # issue here in getting column name as chart title
  labs(title = colnames(feature))

  # labs(title = colnames(x))
  })
```

It looks like small issue but not able to figure out how to get the respective column names for each chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `imap` instead of `map` which will give you access to column names as well as values.

```
library(tidyverse)

list_plot <- gapminder %>% 
              select(where(is.factor)) %>%
              imap(function(feature_value, feature_name) {
                count(data.frame(x = feature_value), x) %>% 
                ggplot(aes(x = x, y = n)) +
                geom_col() +
                theme_minimal() +
                theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
                labs(title = feature_name)
              })
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah for helping me so many times, this is exactly what I was looking for !!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this approach as an option for you. Reshape your data with the factor variables and then summarise to get the counts. Using facets can be of help when setting the titles for each variable. Here the code:

```
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)
#Code
gapminder %>% 
  select_if(is.factor) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  group_by(name,value) %>%
  summarise(N=n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = N)) +
  geom_col(fill='purple',color='black') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  facet_wrap(.~name,nrow = 1,scales = 'free')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Duck, I was actually looking for mapping column names to chart inside map or apply functions only but this is a very interesting approach and I never thought about it. I think I will prefer this approach in future than map functions for this. Thanks again !!